# for the Google re2 library, what does longest_match mean?

Tags: regex, re2

I can't figure out what the longest_match option does in Google's re2 library.

Explanations which are *incorrect*:

- when applying `/a*/` to `"aaaaa"`, setting longest-match makes the Kleene closure greedy so that the regex matches the whole string `"aaaaa"` instead of the empty string `""`.
- when applying `/a*/` to `"abaa"`, setting longest-match makes the regex match the longest match `"aa"` (starting at index 2) instead of the leftmost match `"a"` (starting at index 0)

I haven't been able to find anyone on the internet who discusses this, which suggests that I'm the only one confused.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually POSIX regular expressions return the [*leftmost longest*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/leftmost_longest_rule.html) match. That is (assuming you only search for the first match, which is the default behavior for most regex implementations) the regex `/a*/` will return `"a"` when applied to `"abaa"` because the leftmost `a` (position 0) matches. The regex declares success before having seen the `aa` that follow in position 2.

Other regex libraries (PCRE for example) return the first possible match, so for example

```
a(b|bb)
```

will match `"ab"` in the string `"abb"` because the first alternation already matches.

Now I don't know the `re2` library, but I assume that the `longest_match` option will collect all possible matches from a string and then return the longest one of them.

Comment: your example is exactly the behavior of re2.  Thanks!

Comment: If you apply `/a(b|bb)/` to `xabxabb`, I would expect the match start position to be 1, whether `longest_match` is in force or not.  Your final paragraph isn't that clear, but it sounds like you're saying it will reject the match at position 1 because there's a longer one at position 4.

Comment: right, it should always be the leftmost position.  Also, the ordering of the alternation matters:  `/a(bb|b)/` on `"abb"` returns `"abb"` regardless of `longest_match`.